# NodeJS deploying with Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am trying to upload my NodeJS project on Heroku. The project is a multiplayer game, locally the code works for me and both players enter the same map. But, in Heroku I don't get both players on the same map.

I leave the NODEJS code

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

const jugadores = []

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

class Jugador {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
  }

  asignarMokepon(mokepon) {
    this.mokepon = mokepon
  }

  actualizarPosicion(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }

  asignarAtaques(ataques) {
    this.ataques = ataques
  }
}

class Mokepon {
  constructor(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre
  }
}

app.get("/unirse", (req, res) => {
  const id = `${Math.random()}`

  const jugador = new Jugador(id)

  jugadores.push(jugador)

  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  
  res.send(id)
})

app.post("/mokepon/:jugadorId", (req, res) => {
  const jugadorId = req.params.jugadorId || ""
  const nombre = req.body.mokepon || ""
  const mokepon = new Mokepon(nombre)
  
  const jugadorIndex = jugadores.findIndex((jugador) => jugadorId === jugador.id)

  if (jugadorIndex >= 0) {
    jugadores[jugadorIndex].asignarMokepon(mokepon)
  }
  
  console.log(jugadores)
  console.log(jugadorId)
  res.end()
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Servidor funcionando", PORT)
})
```

I leave a small part of the code here because it is not possible to publish so much code. But I leave a link to the repository on GitHub

Link of the page hosted on Heroku:https://proyecto-mokepon.herokuapp.com/
Code link on GitHub: https://github.com/IamMatiasBazan/proyecto-mokepon

Locally it generates the random number for each player
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArYKr.jpg)

Deployed in Heroku I see this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyAwG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The requests you are sending is pointed to [localhost in your js file](https://github.com/IamMatiasBazan/proyecto-mokepon/blob/53c2d7783483ac59c162e24171e88f4d6418ae1c/public/js/mokepon.js#L262) (multiple places, but this is one). Here you should consider changing it to be the heroku domain or just `/mokepon/${jugadorId}/ataques` (or something else).

It also looks like the app is sending a new request every 50ms, even if nothing happens. In this case I would then suggest you to look into [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to prevent the application to send useless request everytime.

Comment: I tried taking out the localhost and putting in the heroku domain. But it keeps giving me an error.